# How long in advance can Flixbus tickets be booked

Tags: europe, bookings, buses, flixbus

How long time in advance can I book [Flixbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flixbus) bus tickets for traveling in Europe? When I try with a route that normally runs daily (out of Prague) for June 1, 2020, their web site refuses with:

> Unfortunately there are no trips on this route on the selected date

I guess this is because the date is still too far out, perhaps even after their next upcoming change of served routes and timetables. I there any offical communication from Flixbus on this topic?

Comment: Flixbus does not operate any buses, but is just a ticketing platform. The buses are all operated by local operators, so I doubt there is a general rule when tickets become available.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Interesting: did not know that.

Comment: @KristvanBesien That's not true. They do not own busses or employ drivers and like to use the whole “technology company” line but they do have a network planning team. That's not how a ticketing platform works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, it has by now (i.e. a bit less than 6 months in advance of the planned trip) become possible to book those tickets online.